# Get environment variable in c++ - I get NULL

Tags: c++, environment-variables

I am trying to get the contents of an environment variable, IF it exists.

```
#define MY_VAR "MY_ENV_VAR"
//function
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
char const* temp = getenv(MY_VAR);
if(temp != NULL)
{
    string_variable = std::string(temp);            
}   
//code
#pragma warning(default:4996)
```

I thought I was doing the right things, but as soon as I created the environment variable and gave it the default value, I expected temp not to be NULL... Did I expect too much ?

I am in Debug, and I see:

```
temp 0x00000 <Bad Ptr> 
! CXX0030 Error: Expression cannot be evaluated
```

Running "set" in command line shows me the environment variable (System, by the way).

I am in Windows...

Note: I used the pragma warnings because I read that getenv are deprecated or something.

Please give me an idea why I am not getting a valid value. Thank you.

Comment: Is the env-var actually set in the environment in which the program is being run?

Comment: The bug is probably in code you didn't post.

Comment: Restart IDE after changing environment variable.

Comment: I thought that rebuilding would automatically let everyone know about the variable. I just restarted my computer, and everything magically worked. I would like to mark your answer as the answer, if you can post it. Will mark the existing answer as the "answer" otherwise, since it told me that my code worked.

Comment: @Thalia Environment variables are inherited during process creation. Each process has its own environment variables. That means if you change an environment variable for a process, child processes spawned after the change will have it, those before will not. Since your IDE was spawned before the change, it and any processes it spawns will not inherit it. You would need to close it launch it again, provided its parent process has the environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted should work.  It did for me, anyway.  Maybe you didn't get the env variable correct, or the Visual Studio environment didn't have it.  Try this:

```
std::string string_variable;

#define MY_VAR "PATH"
int main()
{
    char const* temp = getenv(MY_VAR);
    if(temp != NULL)
    {
        string_variable = std::string(temp);            
    }   
}
```

Better yet, get rid of the macro so you can see at runtime what is being passes to `getenv`:

```
std::string string_variable;
static const std::string MY_VAR = "PATH";
int main()
{
    char const* temp = getenv(MY_VAR.c_str());
    if(temp != NULL)
    {
        string_variable = std::string(temp);            
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you're right my code worked. I got my second cup of coffee and restarted my computer - and found out that I tried so hard to troubleshoot a non-existing problem. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is OK.
You simply must restart Visual Studio or/and computer after you add/remove environment variable.